# Using Groovy groupBy to transform map

Tags: groovy

I have a list of maps as such

```
[
[name: 'tony', age: 10],
[name: 'peter', age: 15],
[name: 'paul', age: 20],
[name: 'peter', age: 25],
[name: 'paul', age: 30]
]
```

I want to transform this to:

```
[
[name: 'tony', [10],
[name: 'peter', [15, 25],
[name: 'paul', [20, 30]
]
```

I try:

```
myList.groupBy{it.name}
```

But this doesn't work

It give me:

```
[
[name: 'tony', [[name: 'tony', age: 10]],
[name: 'peter', [[name: 'peter', age: 15], [name: 'peter', age: 25]],
[name: 'paul', [[name: 'paul', age: 20], [name: 'paul', age: 30]]
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to manipulate the map a bit after you've grouped it:

```
def lom = [ [name: 'tony', age: 10],
            [name: 'peter', age: 15],
            [name: 'paul', age: 20],
            [name: 'peter', age: 25],
            [name: 'paul', age: 30] ]

def newlom = lom.groupBy { it.name }.collect { k, v ->
    [ name:k, age:v*.age ]
}            

assert newlom == [ [name: 'tony', age:[10]],
                   [name: 'peter', age:[15,25]],
                   [name: 'paul', age:[20,30]] ]
```

(I'm assuming that's the output you wanted, as the output you said you want in the question isn't a valid data-structure) :-)

If you want the structure in thecomment (note the comment isn't valid either, as `peter` appears to be a key?), then try:

```
def newlom = lom.groupBy { it.name }.collect { k, v ->
    [ k, *v.age ]
}            

assert newlom == [ ['tony', 10],
                   ['peter', 15, 25],
                   ['paul', 20, 30] ]
```

Comment: Thanks and what would it be, if I just wanted [["tony", 10], ["peter":15, 25]... i.e. drop the name and age field.  Thanks

Comment: I did the ^^^ by doing: collectEntries{k, v -> [k: v*.sku]}